# Page number position on page with table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, header-footer, positioning, page-numbering, fancyhdr

I want to position page numbers in my document in top-right corner. I managed to do so using `fancyhdr` (see below).

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\hypersetup{%
    pdfborder = {0 0 0}
}
\renewcommand*{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyhf{}
\rhead{\thepage}
\pagestyle{fancy}
```

Everything works fine, except page number on the page where I have table of contents is centered at the bottom of that page.

Does anyone know how to fix that?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Your post was migrated here from another Stack Exchange site. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you need to edit the `plain` settings. For example, adding the following to the preamble may help

```
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
\fancyhf{} % clear all header and footer fields
\fancyhead{} % clear all header fields
\fancyfoot{} % clear all footer fields
\fancyhead[RO]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[LE]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
}
```

Note that in the [`fancyhdr`](http://mirrors.ucr.ac.cr/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/fancyhdr/fancyhdr.pdf) documentation it says that

> Some LaTeX commands, like `\chapter`, use the `\thispagestyle` command to automatically switch to the `plain` page style, thus ignoring the page style currently in eﬀect. To customize even such pages you must redeﬁne the `plain` pagestyle.

Therefore, this includes pages like the `Table of Contents`.

Comment: @marmelade You are most welcome!